# Get value of specific key in Json

Tags: c#, json

i have json like this

```
{\n\t\"username\":\"hunzla\",\n\t\"password\":\"123\"\n}
```

I want to get value of username "hunzla". How can i get it in c#?

Comment: Deserialize the JSON string and access the properties. If you use Json.NET this looks like a simple: `var x=JObject.Parse(json); var name=x[useraname"];` Have you tried something? PS whitespace outside tokens in JSON is ignored so those tabs and newlines don't affect how you deserialize the string,

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c

Comment: @Selvin the `active` tab in the linked question returns some pretty bad answers - both JavascriptSerializer and DataContractSeriazer are obsolete

Answer (score -1):

use **JavascriptSerializer**

first step make a class

using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

```
using System.Globalization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

public partial class Userobject
{
    [JsonProperty("username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("password")]
    public long Password { get; set; }
}
```

//use that class to Deserialize

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();  
BlogSites blogObject = js.Deserialize<Userobject>(jsonData);  
string name = blogObject.username ;  
string description = blogObject.password ;
```

Comment: Definitely not. The class is obsolete and doesn't even handle dates. Even ASP.NET Web API uses JSON.NET

Comment: But it will work its working in my project

Comment: Have you tried deserializing dates?

Comment: then we can use NewtonSoft.JSON